# Chi function with a set of finite measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a set of finite measure and $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. Suppose further that there exists $c$ real number such that $$\int_Ef^n=c\ \ \ \forall\ \ n=2,3,4,...$$
The question is show that there exists a measurable set $A \subseteq E$ such that $f=\chi_{_{A}}.$

$\underline{My\ \ attempt}:$

I honestly have no idea to start here, the only thing I see might help is $$\int_Ef^n=c\ \ \ \forall\ \ n=2,3,4,...$$
but even though I do not know what is $f$ exactly. So I will appreciate any hint or help for that.

Thank you.

Comment: Partition $E$ into sets $E_{<1}$ where $|f|<1$, $E_1$ where $|f|=1$, and $E_{>1}$ where $|f|>1$.  Observe that $|f|^n=f^n$ when $n$ is even.  You may have to do some $\epsilon$ adjustments but this should give you a clue.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: You don't need the "$\ldots$". It suffices when the condition holds for only $n=2,3,4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler than you expect. Note that
$$0 \le \int (f^2 - f)^2 = \int f^4 - \int 2f^3 + \int f^2 = c -2c + c = 0$$
so that $f^2 - f = f(f-1) = 0$ almost everywhere. Thus $f = 0$ or $f=1$ almost everywhere.

Comment: This is not valid. You don't know that $f^{2}-f$ is non-negative so its integral being $0$ does not imply that it is $0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunate typo on my part. I left out the square.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g =f^{2}$. Then $\int g^{n} =c$ for all $n$ and so $c \geq \int_C g^{n}$ where $C=\{|f| >1\}$. By Monotone Convergence Theorem we get $m(\{|f| >1\})=0$. Now $\int g^{n} (1-f) =\int f^{2n}-\int f^{2n+1}=0$ and the integrand is non -negative. Hence  $g^{n} ((1-f)=0$ almost everywhere which gives $f=0$ or $1$  almost everywhere. Hence $f=I_A$ where $A=\{x: f(x)=1\}$.

Comment: How did you use the Monotone Convergence theorem

Comment: @Ahmed On the set $C$ the sequence $g^{n}$ increases to $\infty$ so MCT gives $c \geq \infty \times m(C)$ which would lead to a contradiction if $m(C)>0$.